# How to only get username

Tags: development, user

How could i get only the username from my list?
Right now my username gets displayed as a string so there are some characters in front the username that should not be there?
`18;#Bart Simpsson` like this it gets displayed when getting the data from my list,
My field is of type user

Here is my code

```
Guid fieldID2 = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("FirstNameLastName").Id;
string valueField2 = item[fieldID2].ToString();
Label1.Text=valueField2;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use below code to extract the `SPUser` object

```
string valueField2 = item[fieldID2].ToString();
SPFieldUserValue userField = (SPFieldUserValue)item.Fields[fieldID2].GetFieldValue(valueField2);
SPUser user= userField.User;
```

Now you can access all properties of [SPUser Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser_properties.aspx)

Example `user.LoginName`

Comment: Nice... You beat me to it :)